# Jmeter: While controller

Tags: jmeter

I am load testing a web site.
I have request "A" and "B".
For request "A", i have a parameter field "Quantity", where i am passing values as 1, 10, 15 and 16 through csv files.
And from same request , i am extracting ""Quantity", through regex and passing it to request "B".
Request "B" is placed under while controller and i have user function in while controller as 
${__javaScript(${QUANTITY}<10),}

Request B is executed for infinite time and each time parameter fetched is "1".

Kindly provide your valuable suggestions for above scenario, since i want the request to fetch value "1", execute it and come out of the while loop.

Comment: can you please share the Test Plan screenshot highlighting While controller, and Regular Expression Extractor under Request A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript expression is incorrect

```
${__javaScript(${QUANTITY}<10,)}  - correct one
${__javaScript(${QUANTITY}<10),}  - your one
```

Comma should go after 10, not after the closing bracket. Use [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) in order to create syntaxically correct JMeter Functions.

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more information on using the While Controller